# Doesn't Twitter PowerTrack support past date tweets before the track's createdDate?

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to analyze tweets by Insights for Twitter. I use PowerTrack. I would like to search past tweets before the track's createdDate. I use query option(posted) in order to search past tweets.

When I set the date before the track's createdDate (query 1), I got no tweet. When I set the date after the track's createdDate (query 2), I got many tweets.

Doesn't Twitter PowerTrack support past date tweets before the track's createdDate ?

```
track's createDate: 2015-11-05T04:27:34.747Z
query1(after createDate): posted:2015-11-05T04:28:00Z,2015-11-05T04:33:00Z
-> I got many tweets.

query2(before createData): posted:2015-11-05T04:08:00Z,2015-11-05T04:13:00Z
-> I got no tweet.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerTrack API supports realtime tweets only. It indexes new tweets after you activate the track and stops when you deactivate it or the `endDate` property of the track is reached (this is an optional property). After track is started you can query tweets from it.

Powertrack does not index past tweets. There is another API called Historical Powertrack that can index past tweets, but it is not supported by the Insights for Tweets Bluemix service.

The two queries you created are working as expected based on the track you have.

From the GNIP web site (http://support.gnip.com/faq):

> **What are the technical differences between realtime PowerTrack and
> Historical PowerTrack?**
>
> Realtime PowerTrack provides customers with the
> ability to filter Twitter’s full realtime firehose and data is
> delivered to the customer’s application through a constant stream as
> Tweets are posted. See the realtime PowerTrack Questions section below
> for more details. Historical PowerTrack is a RESTful API that provides
> access to the entire historical archive of public Twitter data – back
> to the first Tweet in March 2006 – using the same rule-based-filtering
> system as realtime PowerTrack. See the Historical PowerTrack Questions
> section below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

PowerTrack Supports only real time streaming. That is if you create a track and setup rules it will start getting filtered data from that moment.
If you want to access the historic data Gnip has given one more tool Historical Powertrack that can give you all the tweets since the beginning.
The restriction with Historical PowerTrack is the end time should be 30 min less than the current time.